# Large static data for ASP.NET webservice?

Tags: asp.net, database, web-services, caching

My system was mentioned in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633634/best-index-strategies-for-read-only-table

because the data is readonly, and in specific time, a part of data (50-200k rows, about 200 byte/each) is intensively queried, so I think allowing client to connect to database and query each row/query is way too expensive. It would be a better choice if I cache part of data (which is being intensively queried) into RAM, which is much faster than SQL Server.

The problem is, the system I'm currently working on is a webservice, so I'm not sure that it allows large static data to be cached. Is my idea a good choice? How my data can "survive" when IIS recycle?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the data into RAM on `Application_Start` event. Then you don't need to worry about IIS restart

Here is an MS guide about [Caching Data at Application Startup](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/caching-data-at-application-startup-cs)

Comment: ..., sorry, but my system is a web service, it's different from a web application